# Best way to turn a ReactApp into an embeddable component for another ReactApp?

Tags: reactjs

I have a small demo application built with React that I would like to embed within another React app that contains a section for multiple demos. What is the best way to go about this without simply rebuilding the small app in the larger app?

Ideally, I would like to have the demo built as a component within a single js file that I could import into the larger app.

Comment: Sounds like you know how to begin approaching the problem. React, by its very nature, is based on combining multiple components into larger applications. If you have built a component or two in one project that you'd like to use in a new project, you can copy the relevant files to the new project and then import the components into the new project. https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting. Once you've made an attempt & you've got code to show, you'll be able to get help debugging your code on here. Show your attempt & we can give you help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.